# How would i make my character slow down to a stop rather than immediately stop

Tags: godot

I'm very new to programming and a using a tutorial I found to create the movement for my first game. it works fine for movement except that the character will stop abruptly is there a way to slowly decrease the velocity when an input is not being pressed. similar to quake for example.

```
 direction.z = Input.get_action_strength("move_backward")-Input.get_action_strength("move_forward")
 direction = direction.normalized()
 direction = direction.rotated(Vector3.UP,rotation.y)
 velocity.x = direction.x * movementSpeed
 velocity.z = direction.z * movementSpeed
 move_and_slide(velocity,Vector3.UP)
```

https://youtu.be/vEuR-Bo0feY here is the video for reference

Answer (score 2):

Get the velocity that `move_and_slide` returns:

```
velocity = move_and_slide(velocity,Vector3.UP)
```

Which is the velocity after dealing with slides and collisions. And we will reduce it:

```
velocity -= velocity * min(delta/stop_time, 1.0)
```

Where `stop_time` is a variable that controls how fast you want it to stop in seconds (the same units of `delta)`. So, if `stop_time = 1.0`, it will stop after one second. Tweak it to what you want. *You may also hard-code the value if you prefer, but I'm suggesting to use a variable.*

Now, idea is that we will keep the velocity for the next time `_physics_process` runs, and only set it to full `movementSpeed` when there is input. So you can check if `direction` is zero, and if it is, don't change `velocity`.

Something like this:

```
if direction.z != 0:
    direction = direction.normalized()
    direction = direction.rotated(Vector3.UP,rotation.y)
    velocity.x = direction.x * movementSpeed
    velocity.z = direction.z * movementSpeed

velocity = move_and_slide(velocity,Vector3.UP)
velocity -= velocity * min(delta/stop_time, 1.0)
```

---

By the way, if you will also add gravity, I suppose you don't want the fall to decelerate too. So, you may want to only want to apply that on the `x` and `z`. The good news that you can do it per component:

```
if direction.z != 0:
    direction = direction.normalized()
    direction = direction.rotated(Vector3.UP,rotation.y)
    velocity.x = direction.x * movementSpeed
    velocity.z = direction.z * movementSpeed

velocity = move_and_slide(velocity,Vector3.UP)
var slowdown := min(delta/stop_time, 1.0)
velocity.x -= velocity.x * slowdown
velocity.z -= velocity.z * slowdown
```

*By the way, multiply gravity by delta when applying to velocity.*

---

And you may not want that <strike>linear</strike> deceleration but some custom easing. You can accomplish that like this:

```
var slowdown := ease(min(delta/stop_time, 1.0), easing_curve)
```

Where `easing_curve` defines the curve used for easing, see [cheat sheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/godotengine/godot-docs/3.4/img/ease_cheatsheet.png).

*For more complex behaviors you will want to use a `Tween`.*